# Disaster Recovery Center for Google Cloud customers in Indonesia

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We subscribed to Google Cloud service for Indonesia, which has a local server in Indonesia as per regulatory requirement. This server is our production server as well as storing data. In case this server hosting data is down, we will need a Disaster Recovery Center (backup server) to switch over. Is it correct to understand that the backup server will be taken care of as part of the Cloud's uptime commitment?

Answer (score 1):

A properly designed business continuity plan is a lot more then requesting an instance from a hosting provider. How the organization keeps running during recovery is also a part of the plan.  And a significant responsibility of maintaining available applications falls on you, even though you no longer manage the physical hardware. You still need to take and restore backups, for example.

Think about your [required RTO and RPO](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/dr-scenarios-planning-guide). Can you afford to be down for 3 hours of unplanned downtime while manually executing recovery? Is last night's backup an acceptable point in time, or do you have to recover every transaction from a database?

Review the available infrastructure and understand their limitations. A single Compute Engine instance is only in one zone (data center). While it can keep running through a number of events, a zone outage like a fire would take it out. You can mitigate this by running a managed instance group across multiple zones. Could even be [a MIG of just one instance](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/dr-scenarios-for-data#recovering_a_database_server_without_synchronizing_state). Or sometimes, you can outsource some of the details to managed services, such as if you make use of Cloud SQL for relational database.

[Design with the locality restriction in mind.](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/architecting-disaster-recovery-for-locality-restricted-workloads) Very easy to launch resources in regions around the world. Put in controls to limit to just your region. To some extent, one limits the DR plans you can execute if the entire region is down. However, with multiple zones, a region is highly redundant. It would take a major event to prevent you from being able to launch instances and restore backups. And multi-regional configuration is a bit more complex, it may not be the design at first.

Test! For example, delete the server and the disks. It should be possible to restore them from backup.